# дополнение к вопросу

Tags: ajax, laravel

Итак, есть маршрут:

```
Route::match(['post','get'],'cabinet',['uses'=> 'CabinetController@index','as'=>'cabinet']);
```

На странице выводятся ссылки: номер заказа, сумма и т.д и дата:

```
<td>
  {!! Html::link(route('cabinet',['id'=>$order->id]),$order->created_at->toDateString() ,['alt'=>'номер заказа','data-id'=>$order->id ,'method'=>'POST','id'=>'azopaReason','class'=>'azopa' ] ) !!} &nbsp гр.
</td>
```

Форма создается в виде таблицы.

Есть ajax запрос:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#azopaReason').on('click',function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
    let id=$(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'cabinet' ,
        //  url: "cabinetItems",
         cache: false,
        data: {id: id},
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        type:   'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(json){
            if(!json) alert("Ошибка!");
            //$('.wrap_result').append('<br/><strong>Выборка выполнена !</strong>').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
            $("#mediumMine").empty();
            // $('#mediumMine').replaceWith(res.content);
           $("#mediumMine" ).append(json.content);


        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Ошибка передачи id !");
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Есть контроллер, привожу кусок:

```
public function index()
{

    $user=Auth::user();
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->home();
    }
    // если данные переданы методом POST
   $request=Request::createFromGlobals();
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $input = $request->except('_token');
        $this->template=env('THEME').'.both_barsCab';
        $id=$input['id'];
        $alias=$user->id;
        $role_id=3;
        $orders=$this->getOrders($role_id,$alias);
        $orders->load('users','order_items');
        $points=$orders[0]->order_items;
        $priznak=1;

        $content = view(env("THEME") . ".orders_cabinet")->with(["orders"=> $orders,'priznak' =>$priznak,'id'=>$id,'points'=>$points])->render();

        return Response::json(["success"=>true, "content"=>$content]);

    }
```

Так вот, при клике на 1-ю запись срабатывает нормально - идет запрос POST, при клике на все остальные записи идет запрос GET. 
Если кто может, объясните дураку, что делаю не так !

Comment: У вас onclick на id висит, соответственно обрабатывается первый(по структуре) id. id на странице должен быть один.

Answer (score 1):

На страничке много элементов с одним id (`id="azopaReason"`). При попытке привязать `onclick` по идентификатору, привязка осуществляется только к первому элементу. Поэтому, нажатие на первую ссылку обрабатывается скриптом. А остальные ссылки работают как обычно.

Добавте в свою функцию `alert` и увидите, что функция вызывается только для первой ссылки.

Сделайте привязку по классу и все заработает. Например, так:

```
$('a.azopa').on('click',function(e){
```

И еще пара замечаний:

Вместо `$user=Auth::user(); $alias=$user->id;` можно делать так `$alias=Auth::id();`

А вместо `$request=Request::createFromGlobals();` можно просто добавить первый параметр в функцию. То есть, сделать так: `public function index(Request $request)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, спасибо!
Все нормально, первый ответ был правильным. У меня зашел ум за разум. Относительно, create from globals- это тип Симфони, который лежит в основе Laravel. Всем спасибо за участие.